# Why is Okabe the only one to be called by his last name?

Tags: steins-gate

How come that of all the characters of *Steins;Gate*, Okabe is consistently called by his last name, while everyone else is called by their first name? Even his alter ego is called by first name.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't as much of a pattern as you seem to think. Many characters go by nicknames.

Rintarou is nicknamed Oka-rin by Mayushii, as a portmanteau of **Oka**be and **Rin**tarou

Mayuri is nicknamed Mayushii, the same pattern : **Shii**na **Mayu**ri. Daru toys with it by making it Mayu+ the honorific -shi. As childhood friends, Rintarou uses her first name.

Itaru goes by Daru, again a similar pattern : Hashi**da** Ita**ru**. Kurisu calls him Hashida-san

Kurisu is referred to differently by everyone:

> 'Assistant' by Rintarou, then later Kurisu as a sign of affection

> Kurisu-chan (pronounced Chris-chan) by Mayuri. I figure this is because Mayuri is making an effort for Kurisu. It's strongly implied that Kurisu is meant as Chris and confirmed that at her American University she is called that

> Makise-shi by Itaru, her last name with the same -shi honorific

> Makise Kurisu by Suzuha, as she's a famous name to her

In japanese, the default is to go by last name. Since everyone has a nickname (whether affectionate or derogatory) it might seem like it stands out.

But whenever 2 characters don't know each other much, they use the last name with the san honorific. This is especially noticeable in the `0` sequel when many more characters appear. Notably an American character refers to Rintaro by his first name as is traditional in english.

The reverse is more common, having the cast go by last name except for the Protagonist